# What's wrong with my Spring 3.2 / Freemarker config?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, configuration, app-config, freemarker

When I hit the /calendar URL of my Spring 3.2 application the COntroller code is hit successfuly and the view 'calendar' is set in the ModelAndView object.

I get an error from spring about not being able to resolve the view 'calendar', which should point at /WEB-INF/views/calendar.ftl

Spring: 3.2
Freemarker: 2.3.20

I know the view name is set correctly because the error is about not being able to resolve that view.

My Java config:

```
public class YhjInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    servletContext.addFilter("Sitemesh", yhj.web.filters.SitemeshFilter.class).addMappingForServletNames(null, false, "/*");

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(MvcConfiguration.class);
    ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

    DispatcherServlet springServlet = new DispatcherServlet(ctx);
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", springServlet);
    servlet.addMapping("/");
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);

    // want to load some data, eg club list for app scope here?
}
```

}

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"yhj"})
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/css/").addResourceLocations("/resources/css/**");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/js/").addResourceLocations("/resources/js/**");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/img/").addResourceLocations("/resources/img/**");
}

@Bean(name = "viewResolver")
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    FreeMarkerViewResolver resolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
    resolver.setCache(true);
//      resolver.setPrefix("");
    resolver.setSuffix(".ftl");
    return resolver;

}

@Bean(name="freemarkerConfig")
public FreeMarkerConfig freeMarkerConfig() {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("number_format","0.##");
    props.setProperty("locale","en-GB");

    Configuration configuration =   new Configuration();
    configuration.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");

    FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
    configurer.setFreemarkerSettings(props);
    configurer.setConfiguration(configuration);
    configurer.setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/views/");

    return configurer;

}
}
```

Controller method (I'm happy the request is hitting this method):

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/calendar", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView calendarPage(ModelAndView mv){
    mv.setViewName("calendar");
    mv.addObject("events",eventService.getAll());
    return mv;
}
```

I don't think other areas of the application (eg sitemesh) are getting in the way but if that may help in diagnosis I'll share that too.

The error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/yhj] threw 
exception [Could not resolve view with name 'calendar' in servlet with name 
'dispatcher'] with root cause javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view 
with name 'calendar' in servlet with name 'dispatcher'
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1190)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

To me it seems 'calendar' from the controller is not being converted to the file location '/WEB-INF/views/calendar.ftl', so maybe a ViewResolver issue.

Is my config there correct?

EDIT/Update:
Just noticed it appears the request to /calendar is happening twice each time I refresh the page. Perhaps some circular reference in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have fixed it...at least I'm getting a page rendered now which is coming from the FTL.

In case someone stumbles on this question I'll add some notes.

Changes made:

```
@Bean(name="freemarkerConfig")
public FreeMarkerConfig freeMarkerConfig() {
```

is now...

```
@Bean
public FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfig() {
```

Notice the addition of "urer" to the Type returned!

I removed pretty much all the config within this method so the method is now simply:

```
FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
configurer.setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/views/");
return configurer;
```

At some point I'll reinstate stuff.

Because I removed references to the COnfiguration class within this method I can reorganise my imports and use @Configuration on the class instead of the fully qualified spring..Configuration class.